# Selenium screenshot not accurate after Click()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015

I'm using selenium via Visual Studio, and the Chrome Web Driver.

So far, so good. Now I want to take a screenshot of my web page after I click on a hamburger menu (the end goal is to have a screen shot of my webpage with the hamburger menu expanded).

Using Selenium I have

```
        _webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

        IWebElement menu = _webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("hamburgerLink"));

        var screenshot = _webDriver.GetScreenshot();

        menu.Click();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //test
        var fileName = "myImage.png";
        var origFile = _testImagesPersistentPath + fileName;
        screenshot.SaveAsFile(origFile, OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

This saves as expected, but when I review the image, the image is of my webpage before the click has executed (a closed hamburger menu). I might as well take the screenshot before the `menu.Click();`

As you can see I've added a `Sleep(5000)` after `menu.Click();` to test, but the same issue continues...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change the statement postion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **do** take the screenshot before the `menu.Click();`. You just save it to a file afterwards

```
menu.Click();
var screenshot = _webDriver.GetScreenshot();
```

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change the statement position

instead of this :

```
    var screenshot = _webDriver.GetScreenshot();
    menu.Click();
```

change this:

```
    menu.Click();
    var screenshot = _webDriver.GetScreenshot();
```